# Describe data that increased constantly

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to describe a series of number

100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150

Can I say number increase from 100 to 150 by 10? how to emphasize it increases by **adding** 10?

Comment: Incremented by 10

Comment: Or don't use English, use maths ... y = 100 + 10x

Comment: They increase in steps of 10.

Comment: If it simply increases by an arbitrary amount (or remains unchanged), never decreasing, then it is *monotonically increasing*.  If it increases by fixed amounts it is *incrementally increasing by 10* or *increasing in steps of 10* or some such.

Answer (score 3):

You could say that the number **increases [linearly](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+linear)** by 10:

> arranged in or extending along a straight or nearly straight line.
>
> *"linear arrangements"*
>
> **synonyms:** straight, direct, undeviating, as straight as an arrow; sequential
>
> *"linear motion"*
>
> progressing from one stage to another in a single series of steps;
>   sequential.
>
> *"a linear narrative"*

Compare this to a number that increases non-linearly: 10, 100, 1000, 10000.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what your context is, but if you are dealing with a mathematically savvy audience, two terms you need to know are *arithmetic sequence* and *geometric sequence.*  There are dozens of sources on the net if you search these terms.  I will simply draw from my ten years of experience as a mathematics educator.

An arithmetic sequence is one which has a *common difference* between subsequent terms.  The common difference is added to each term to get the next term.  For example:

> 4, 7, 10, 13, 16...
>
> 8, 3, -2, -7, -12, ...

In the first sequence, the common difference is 3, and in the second, -5.

A geometric sequence is one which has a *common ratio* between subsequent terms.   The common ratio is multiplied by each term to get the next term.  Examples:

> 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...
>
> 12, 4, 1.333, 0.444, 0.148148, ...

In the first sequence the common ratio is 2, and in the second is 1/3.

**Your example is an arithmetic sequence with first term 100 and common difference 10.**

Answer (score 1):

You might say:

> The series of numbers shows a linear increase between 100 and 150 in increments of 10.